# Django aggregate avg price by product category

Tags: python, django

I have this view:

```
def MainStatsView(request):
    leads = Leads.objects.all()
    university = University.objects.all()
    price = Leads.objects.aggregate(Avg('price'))


    context = {
            'leads':leads,
            'university':university,
            'price':price,
            }

    return render(request,'stats/stats_main.html',context)
```

I am trying to get the average price of properties (the product) that generated leads at each university (the category). I am having trouble finding the avg price based on university. I tried using a for loop but that doesn't seem to do the trick.

Also here is my loop:

```
{% for uni in university %}
    <tr>
        <td>{{ uni.u_name }}</td>
        <td>{{ price }}</td>
        <td>{{ lead.school }}</td>
        <td>{{ lead.featured }}</td>
        <td>{{ lead.price }}</td>
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

The **Leads** model:

```
class Leads(models.Model):
    listing = models.CharField(max_length=100,default='Listing')
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    company = models.CharField(max_length=50,default='Company')
    school = models.CharField(max_length=100,default='School')
    featured = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    price = models.IntegerField(blank=False,default=500)
    student_name = models.CharField(max_length=50,default='Name')
    student_phone = models.CharField(max_length=50,default='Phone')
    student_email = models.EmailField(max_length=100,default='none@studentcribz.com')
    party_size = models.IntegerField(max_length=1,default=1)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.school
```

The **University** model:

```
class University(models.Model):
    u_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    u_name = models.CharField(max_length=100,blank=False)
    u_slug = models.CharField(max_length=100,blank=True)
    name_initials = models.CharField(max_length=5,blank=False)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=100,blank=False)
    color1 = models.CharField(max_length=7,blank=False)
    color2 = models.CharField(max_length=7,blank=False)
    color3 = models.CharField(max_length=7,blank=False)
    u_logo = models.ImageField(upload_to='university_logos',blank=False)
    banner = models.ImageField(upload_to='university_banners',blank=False)
    u_homepage_pic = models.ImageField(default='',upload_to='university_homepage_pic',blank=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.u_name

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.u_slug = slugify(self.u_name)
        super(University, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

I'm a little all over the place here so that is why it looks overly messy. Here is an image of the result. It's giving me the avg on the price of all properties that have generated leads rather than for one school specifically (which is what I want).

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In Django you can generate aggregates over an entire queryset using `aggregate()` or an independent summary for each object using `annotate()`. [Here is the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/aggregation/#generating-aggregates-over-a-queryset).

In your case, it seems you want to annotate the average `lead__price` to each university object:

```
university = University.objects.all().annotate(Avg('lead__price'))
```

Note you may have to adjust the `lead__price` reference so that it matches your data model, which you haven't provided.

Comment: Sorry I updated the post to show the models. I am using data from 2 models so it might be a little more involved then one line.

Comment: I may have missed it, but are there no `ForeignKey`s linking your models?

Comment: You got it, no `ForeignKey`s

Comment: If you want to use Django's methods for doing the annotation, then you'll need to provide a `ForeignKey` so that Django understands how the models relate to each other. If you cannot take that approach, then you'll need to implement the logic yourself.

Comment: So just to make sure I understand correctly, the "School" field in my `Leads model` should be a `ForeignKey` to the `University model`?

Comment: Yes if that is how your data is structured, then it would be good to add that connection between the models. As a general principle, time spent upfront to set up a good data model will help to greatly reduce the resulting code complexity.